# AWS permission error when using IAM policy for lambda function to conditionally allow dynamodb getitem

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I am facing an AWS IAM issue. I have:

- A dynamodb table whose primary key consists of userid.
- A cognito identity pool which maps the user's cognito pool sub to a principal tag username
- A lambda function which is invoked with credentials from the cognito identity pool.

I am trying to create an IAM policy for the lambda function so that the lambda can only access items whose primary key is same as the username. I have tried the following template, but I get only access denied errors with it:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                        "${aws:PrincipalTag/username}"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:GetItem"
            ],
            "Resource": "TableARN",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If I provide an exact username in place of "${aws:PrincipalTag/username}" then it works.

Comment: How are the Cognito users invoking the Lambda function? Via API Gateway REST API?

Comment: @jarmod via lambda function url with signature v4

Comment: Believe that the IAM principal in play when that policy is evaluated is the IAM role associated with the invoked Lambda function. It won't be the IAM user or Cognito user's assumed IAM role that was used to sign the URL. Does the `event` that is passed into the Lambda function when the function URL is requested identify the original signer of the URL?

Comment: I assumed that the `PrincipalTag` would propagate. No, I can't securely identify the original signer. I get the cognito identity pool id, but not the user pool sub. Should I send the `idtoken` in the `event` and  parse it manually to get the sub claim?